# OSX Based Equivalents for Stacking Normal Maps?

Tags: textures, normal-mapping, plugin

I've been looking for an OSX based alternative to the Windows based [xNormal](http://www.xnormal.net/Downloads.aspx) and [NVIDIA textures tools](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-adobe-photoshop) for stacking normal maps in photoshop.

Can anyone recommend something, whether it's a standalone package or photoshop plugin?

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested that I try out [nDo](http://quixel.se/nDo1/), which looks like it might do what I want.
It's a PS plugin that works in both Windows and OSX so here's hoping :)